# How to determine which class is sent to the method?

Tags: java, polymorphism

I have a method called Register, I need to find out which class object is send to this method, my code is as following, that does not compile

Error is can not find Symbol

symbol: class T

- Please note I have two type of classes UserTypeA and UserTypeB

Code

```
   public class UserTypeA {
      private int SSN;
      private int Name;
         .... Getter and setters go here....
   }

   public class UserTypeB {
      private int Name;
        ... Getter and setters go here ....
   }


   public void mymethod(){

     UserTypeA usera = new UserTypeA();
     usera.setName("Jack");
     register(usera);

     UserTypeB userb = new UserTypeB();
     userb.setName("Daniel");
     register(userb);
   }



   public void register(Class<T> type){

      type.registerUser(type.getName());

   }
```

As Jayamohan suggested in his answer blew I have tried the following but it does not have access to getName method.

```
    public void register(Object obj) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    if(obj instanceof UserTypeA)
    { 
        System.out.println(obj.getName());
    }
```

Comment: Does this code even compile? What are the definitions of `UserA` and `UserB`?

Comment: find out which class in what way? its name?

Comment: `instanceof` might be your friend here

Comment: @Code-Guru, does not compile

Comment: @pianoman, give me an example, please

Comment: @DanielMorgan When your code doesn't compile, we need the errors in order to help you. I have posted an answer with some guesses because I think you are missing some key concepts about how classes work.

Comment: @DanielMorgan Please include some of the code for UserTypeA and UserTypeB. In particular, do either of these extend a base class?

Comment: You need to cast the object to `UserTypeA` before calling `getName()`.

Comment: Your question as stated has nothing to do with polymorphism, even though you have tagged it as such. If you really need the two `UserTypeA` and `UserTypeB` classes, you might consider creating a parent class for them. This will allow you to use polymorphism and make your code a little more Java-friendly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25187/discussion-between-daniel-morgan-and-code-guru)

Comment: @Code-Guru, agree but if I create a User class and make these class to extend from that how to pass the value of different forms to the action?

Comment: @Code-Guru, because forms are different.

Answer (score 1):

Change your register method to use `instanceof` keyword as below

```
public void register(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof UserA) {
        // Do something related to UserA
    } else if (obj instanceof UserB) {
        // Do something related to UserB
    }
}
```

Comment: I used it but when I try to access getName() method of any of the objs it does not accept it.

Comment: Try obj.getClass().getName();

Comment: Your query is to find the name of the Object that is being passed to register method right?

Comment: Actually I need to know which class object is sent to method and take an action.

Comment: @DanielMorgan Then use instanceof or get the name of the class; what's the issue? Also, ew; this is nothing like I was talking about in your earlier question.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect that you only need a single `User` *class*, rather than `UserA` and `UserB` classes. Then you can create two `User` *objects* from that class. Then you can simply change your code to the following:

```
   public void mymethod(){

     User jack = new User();
     jack.setName("Jack");
     register(jack);

     User dan = new User();
     dan.setName("Dan");
     register(dan);
   }

   public void register(User newUser){

      // Do something here to register the newUser

   }
```

Note that this code still won't compile by itself. You will also need to create the `User` class itself in a separate file. I don't know what your requirements are, so I can't give any suggestions on what you need to do for this part.

Comment: thanks for your response but please note I have two classes , UserA and UserB

Comment: @DanielMorgan Please edit your original question to include the code for those two classes.